# Does a one-Flutter-file experimentation workflow exist?

Tags: flutter

**Motivation**

I would like to clean up my Flutter directories early on, not as an afterthought. I know that after a few years I'll have dozens if not hundreds of samples, experimentations, and half-hearted attempts, both my own and from SO or elsewhere. Then I'll want to clean all this up and keep just the actual source files.

Rather than gather up 500KB per sample, with 400 to 2000+ files (depending on the number of target platforms) and clean up later, I'd like to set things up right now so that it's clean from the beginning, and no clean-up is needed later on.

**Question**

I am a (deeply committed [yes, "*there's always one of those*"]) Emacs user who is learning Flutter. While experimenting I type

```
flutter create newproject
(edit lib/main.dart in Emacs)
(compile and run)
```

Afterwards I type

```
> du -hs newproject
460K    newproject
```

I understand that the intermediate files—whether the target is iOS, Android, or the web—must be saved somewhere. Still, these intermediate files are, at least during a learning phase, entirely discardable, and the fact that the logic fits in just one file is quite admirable, being a great improvement over coding in XML+Java/Kotlin or in XML-Storyboard+Swift.

Does there exist a workflow that would enable me to say: this directory consists of 30 different `main.dart`s; I'd run something from the command line based on just one file, take a 30 second break, and come back when the intermediate files have been generated?

To be clear, it's entirely easy to write a short script to do this on my side. Here I'm wondering whether I can avoid reinventing the wheel, in particular that anything I do will certainly be far less featured than a (semi-)official solution.

Comment: I believe it doesn't exist an official way to do that, the closest is to use a sample (`flutter create --sample=widgets.SingleChildScrollView.1 mysample`), but that would only change the main.dart content, all the other structure would be created. I believe a script is the easier choice. Also thinking about tinkering with emacs , how the experience with flutter?

Comment: @croxx5f The support under Emacs is simply superb. The best I've seen so far in programming support (and Emacs nerds use Emacs for everything, not just for writing source code) is flycheck under Python. Still, the flutter support exceeds even that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close to what you want with `flutter create`. If you specify all the same parameters, it will attempt to rebuild rather than replace everything each time. It will overwrite the iOS/Android files as necessary, but it will not overwrite `main.dart`.

One way to do it is as follows. You can keep an arbitrary number of your experiments in (`lib/main1.dart`, `lib/main2.dart`, ...) within a single project. You'd keep all the "intermediate" files in place. You can then run different `main.dart` files just by typing, for example, `flutter run -d "<device>" lib/main2.dart` from the same project.

Technically, all your Dart files would still belong to the same project, but you'd be launching just one screen at a time. The screen you're launching would run independently from the remaining n-1 main.dart files in `lib`.

However, each time you run one `main_n.dart`, it will replace the existing app on the phone (they'd all have the same app id as that's defined in the native side of things). This is suitable for experimenting quickly, but wouldn't be good for actually publishing.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit your answer to make sure I understood. Do you mind if I do? I'd basically confirm: The directory `lib` can contain an unlimited number of Dart files (`main1.dart`, `main2.dart`, ...). These correspondent to **independent** projects. It is then enough to type `flutter run -d "<device>" lib/main17.dart` to run that code, **independently** from the `n-1` main.dart files in `lib`. Is this an accurate statement?

Comment: Go for it re: editing the answer =). But hmm, I wouldn't necessarily call them independent projects, but each could be run and would result in a different screen being shown depending on what was in that particular file. However, each time you run one, it will replace the existing app on the phone (they'd all have the same app id as that's defined in the native side of things).

Like I said, not sure exactly what your goal is - that would work well to experiment with a bunch of different things quickly, but wouldn't be at all ideal for actually publishing.

Comment: Cool. That's what I'm looking for. I'll edit your answer to add the detaild I'm hoping for, and, if necessary, you'll edit it to correct it.

Comment: Another trick would have been nice, but I can't get it to work. Set up a soft link from `main.dart` to one of the files in `lib` (`hello_world.dart`, `increment_counter.dart`, ...) and launch by running `flutter run -d C4747533-..-4837 lib/main.dart`. Then to switch from one app (one screen, really) to another, modify the soft link, and press either `r Hot reload. ` or `R Hot restart.`. But neither a hot reload nor a hot restart works. `flutter run` doesn't seem to actually re-read the `main.dart` file.

Comment: Hmm. That's too bad but maybe not surprising, it might follow symlinks on its initial runthrough. One thing you could try, which wouldn't be quite what you asked for originally but would have essentially the same result, is to have a main.dart which contained a stateful widget which simply loads in another stateful widget - you could define your various files with copies of that widget, and to switch you'd just change the import and Hot Restart. It would mean having the logic split across multiple files... but realistically not a huge difference.

Comment: You _could_ even try having one main.dart file with a main function which does nothing but call a main function from another file and having it import whichever of your other files, although I don't have full confidence that even Hot Restart would actually work with that. Worth a try if you're set on doing it this way though! (ie.. `import 'main2.dart' as realmain` ... `realmain.main(....)`,)

Comment: You're right. That's well worth trying. My objective is basically cleaning up early. I know that after a few years I'll have dozens if not hundreds of samples, experimentations, and half-hearted attempts, both my own and from SO or elsewhere. Then I'll want to clean all this up and keep just the actual source files. Rather than gather up 500KB per sample, with 400 to 2000+ files (depending on the number of target platforms) and clean up later, I'd rather set things up right now so that it's clean from the beginning, and no clean-up is needed later on.